# Twitter datasets for Neo4j?

Tags: twitter, neo4j

I'm looking for example Twitter **datasets** (not patterns, articles or blogposts) for use with Neo4j.  The Neo4j website lists "Twitter Connections Heroku Waza 2013", but it no longer appears to be accessible.

Comment: Are you looking for a .zip of a neo4j database? I have a database that looks like this: http://i.imgur.com/4h98bp2.png

Let me know if I should link you the .zip or if you're looking for a different format.

Comment: Sure, that would work great Nicole

Comment: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/94782892/tweets.zip It's version 2.1 I believe. Just a small sample of how one might store tweets in  a graph. It doesn't have any information on who follows who, though.

Comment: Still working on updating the datasets, sorry for the delay.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Going to go ahead and add my comments as an answer:

Get the zip here: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/94782892/tweets.zip

This is a small database (neo4j version 2.1.1) of tweets of the following structure:

[image]

Comment: Hello Nicole, is possible to post also the dataset that you've used in "Graphs R Cool"? I have tried commands that you've mentioned in "Graphs R Cool" on above dataset e.g.: MATCH (u:User) WHERE u.followers IS NOT NULL RETURN u; but it gives me different values than was in your video. I know you have posted on your github profile some how to for creating such dataset, but would it be problem to upload it e.g. to Dropbox? PS: I very like your presentation about neo4j with R the only thing I am missing is mentioned dataset. Thank you very much.